# "Rare words" on vocabulary

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to create a sentiment analysis model and I have a question.

After I preprocessed my tweets and created my vocabulary I've noticed that I have words that appear less than 5 times in my dataset (Also there are many of them that appear 1 time). Many of them are real words and not gibberish. My thinking is that if I keep those words then they will get wrong "sentimental" weights and gonna make my model worse.
Is my thinking right or am I missing something?

My vocab size is around 40000 words and those that are "rare" are around 10k.Should I "sacrifice" them?

Comment: Often words with few counts are removed. Simply because they do not generalise. Just give it a try with removing words with low count (more or less agressively). Check back with your test error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of dropping rare words or incorporating them risking their scarcity in the training data leads to poor predictions, you can opt for a third alternative: using a subword vocabulary.

You can use approaches like [byte-pair encoding (BPE)](https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P16-1162.pdf) to extract a subword vocabulary, that removes the out-of-vocabulary word problem and reduces data sparsity in general. There is the [canonical python implementation](https://github.com/rsennrich/subword-nmt) as well as the popular implementation by Google called [sentencepiece](https://github.com/google/sentencepiece).